# How do you say that a song is catchy and stuck in your head?

Tags: translation

My best: "Tiel mojosa! Ĝi vere fiksiĝis en mia kapo, nun."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mi trovis jenajn tradukojn por la vorto *catchy*:

orelkapta, facile memorebla ([vikivortaro](https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vortaro_angla-Esperanta_c))

orelplaĉa, orelflata (Granda Vortaro Hispana-Esperanta)

[ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/frap.html#frap.orel0a) tradukas la vorton *orelfrapa* al la hispana kun tiu senco de *catchy*, sed ne donas anglan tradukon:

> **orelfrapa**: Kiun oni rimarkas pro ĝia aparta, rimarkinda sono: *Espo Despo estas internacia muzikgrupo kiu kreadas kaj prezentas proprajn ritmajn – ofte dancigajn kaj orelfrapajn kantojn*

Tekstaro donas la jenan frazon:

> Esperanto Desperado estas dana/pola/bosnia grupo kiu kantas ritmajn,
>   humoristajn kaj orelfrapajn kantojn origine verkitajn en Esperanto.

Ŝajnas al mi ke *orelkapta* estas plej proksima al la angla *catchy* (to catch = kapti), sed *orelfrapa* estas pli ofte uzata laŭ Google, kvankam ties signifo ŝajnas pli ampleksa ol la unua (ekz. el Tekstaro: *Regis stranga silento, ia orelfrapa silento, kian oni rimarkas, kiam longedaŭra kaj forta bruo subite ĉesas*).

Answer (score 4):

How about *orelvermo* after German *Ohrwurm* (of which English *earworm* is also a calque)?

> Ĉi tiu kanto estas vera orelvermo!

Answer (score 3):

Tiu kanto fariĝis gurdaĵo en mia kapo.

Answer (score 0):

- *kaptema* = catchy
- *infekta* (figure) = stuck